# How to find the IP address of MicroK8

Tags: kubernetes, nginx-ingress, microk8s

I am fairly new to K8 and am working on a setup on my sandbox environment to be replicated on some Ubuntu VMs at a client site.

I have a number of services running within my cluster and ingress rules set up to route to them.  Ingress Add-on is enabled.  I am now trying to expose the endpoints (via Ingress) outside of the machine on which MicroK8s is installed.

I have set up an nginx (edge) proxy server outside of my cluster and am looking for the MicroK8s IP address I need to proxy to. (In production I'll have an edge proxy that takes https and proxies to http)

I have had this working previously on minikube where I proxied to the IP address returned by
minikube ip, but I cannot find a corresponding command on microK8s

Can anyone advise how to do this routing? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was that I had learned Kubernetes using minikube and it handles ingress differently.

Moving to MicroK8 I had to add my own instance of an ingress service class (NodePort) in my ingress namespace and expose port 80. This then exposed my ingress endpoints on all external network interfaces, and my self provisioned edge proxy server was just able to redirect to port 80 on the K8 host machine's public IP